# Python-doit dependecy on a dataset in an h5 file

Tags: python, doit

I have a doit task which depends on one of several datasets contained in an h5 file.

Does anyone have any idea how I could (1) check the dependency to determine whether or not to execute the task and (2) save the dependency's signature for checking next time the task is executed?

Comment: I noticed a downvote.  Is there some way in which I should reframe my question?

Answer (score 1):

In `doit` you can write custom rules to check if a task is up-to-date or not. Check `uptodate` http://pydoit.org/dependencies.html#uptodate